# Having an issue doing a WP_Query with post_content and category__and

Tags: query-posts, wp-query

This is the array for my arguments for the WP_Query.

```
Array
(
    [showposts] => 4
    [paged] => 1
    [post_type] => post
    [post_content] => tree
    [category__and] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 28
        )

)
```

I want to return the posts where they are in the categories 6, 15, 28 and where the post_content has the word tree.

My problem is that I'm returning several duplicated results for the posts that have the word tree in it. Ideally I would like to return one.

anyone have any idea how I can fix or improve this?

Comment: Where are you getting post_content from? To the best of my knowledge, that's not a valid thing to pass to a WP_Query. That isn't how the search works. Searching uses the "s" parameter, and it searches both post_title and post_content. As far as I know, setting the post_content in the query to "tree" or anything else would do nothing whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, I shouldn't have been trying to filter on post_content, but rather 's'

e.g.

```
Array
(
[showposts] => 4
[paged] => 1
[s] => post
[post_content] => tree
[category__and] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 15
        [2] => 28
    )

)
```

Comment: So, you're searching for anything containing the word "post"?